# Should similar jUnit test cases reside within the same test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Okay, so I have a coursework problem sheet I've just finished, I know it works fine but I wanted to write some jUnit tests for it just as some testing practice. It sparked some questions. I wrote a function called `count` which takes in an `int n` and sums up all values from `1 to n` and returns it. So, I wrote 4 test cases for this and assumed they should all go within the same test method as such:

```
@Test
    public void testCount() {
        assertEquals(0, SimmonsPS5.count(0)); // 1 obj in table with name => 0 permutations
        assertEquals(1, SimmonsPS5.count(1)); // 2 obj in table with name => 1 permutation
        assertEquals(3, SimmonsPS5.count(2)); // 2 obj in table with name => 3 permutations (3c2)
        assertEquals(5050, SimmonsPS5.count(100)); // 100 obj in table with name => 100c2 permutations (100(100+1)/2)
    }
```

But then if one fails the test (which will probably mean they all do) the error reporter will only say that one test failed, which is not correct.

Next, my main method in the class instantiates the class, runs a few functions then prints to `stdout`. The main method does this by first taking in one parameter (file name) and then reading the file and doing some operations on it. So I want to test that it outputs the correct data for each file - should each of these test cases reside in the same test method, or separate ones? I opted for separate ones, but only down to the sole reason that I feel as though these are more prone to failure than the previous method. So if this is the correct way to test it, what should the test method be called? `testMain1`, `testMain2` etc? What is the 'accepted' nomenclature?

My `main` test case:

```
private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

@Before
public void setUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
}

@After
public void cleanUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(null);
    System.setErr(null);
}

@Test
public void testMain4in() {
    SimmonsPS5.main(new String[]{"4.in"});
    assertEquals(47485, Integer.parseInt(outContent.toString().trim()));
}

@Test
public void testMain5in() {
    SimmonsPS5.main(new String[]{"5.in"});
    assertEquals(1667, Integer.parseInt(outContent.toString().trim()));
}

@Test
public void testMain6in() {
    SimmonsPS5.main(new String[]{"6.in"});
    assertEquals(45871, Integer.parseInt(outContent.toString().trim()));
}

@Test
public void testMain7in() {
    SimmonsPS5.main(new String[]{"7.in"});
    assertEquals(324, Integer.parseInt(outContent.toString().trim()));
}

@Test
public void testMain8in() {
    SimmonsPS5.main(new String[]{"8.in"});
    assertEquals(1057527, Integer.parseInt(outContent.toString().trim()));
}
```

Note that the output to `stdout` is a single integral number.

Comment: Also, I realise similar questions have been asked before - but none have presented cases as I have - so please read my question thoroughly before blindly marking as a duplicate :) .

Comment: 1 test can have many assertions, if that is the question

Comment: @KeirSimmons I guess your idea is that number of failing tests is some kind of measure of code quality. I would say that ==0 is good and >0 needs fixing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want each test to test a specific feature. All of the tests performed should collectively be able to indicate if the feature is working correctly or isn't. So, e.g., in your first example:

```
@Test
public void testCount() {
    assertEquals(0, SimmonsPS5.count(0)); // 1 obj in table with name => 0 permutations
    assertEquals(1, SimmonsPS5.count(1)); // 2 obj in table with name => 1 permutation
    assertEquals(3, SimmonsPS5.count(2)); // 2 obj in table with name => 3 permutations (3c2)
    assertEquals(5050, SimmonsPS5.count(100)); // 100 obj in table with name => 100c2 permutations (100(100+1)/2)
}
```

This would be appropriate. You are testing to see if `count()` is behaving as designed. If *any* of those fail, then `count()` is not behaving as designed.

It does not matter *how* many of those tests fail -- the action you take if all of them fail will be the same as the action you take if one of them fails: Debug `count()`.

Your second case:

> The main method does this by first taking in one parameter (file name) and then reading the file and doing some operations on it. So I want to test that it outputs the correct data for each file - should each of these test cases reside in the same test method, or separate ones?

Whether or not you combine these into a single test depends on, conceptually, what you are testing. Are you testing to see if `main()` works? Or are you testing to see if it works on a single, specific file? The former would be a more conceptually correct test, as you don't actually *care* that it works on your specific files, you *really* care that it works as designed for any files, and you come up with a set of test files that you believe accurately represents the types of files the program will operate on.

Comment: I can't believe we agree on that one ;)

Comment: @NiklasB. That's twice in one day!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you suggest to test all of the `main` calls within a single `testMain` method?

However, just because a single method, say `count(int i)` fails multiple times, it may fail for different reasons (corner cases etc) - is this not enough of a justification for multiple test methods?

Comment: @Keir: Well if a test fails, you are going to debug anyway to find out the reasons, correct?

Comment: @KeirSimmons I do suggest testing all of `main` in a single test. As for corner cases: It depends. If the corner cases are truly special cases, and the logic for handling them in `count()` is different, *and you would gain something by knowing those specific tests failed*, then yes, separate tests would be useful. If you would not gain anything by knowing those *specific* tests failed then, no, same test.

Comment: Thank you, best answer I've had on SO in a while now :) .